# Most correct way of tracking internationalised site?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have an ecommerce site which displays slightly different content depending on where you're browsing from, e.g.:

- [www.myDomain.com](http://www.myDomain.com) - base domain
- [www.myDomain.com/eu](http://www.myDomain.com/eu) - for EU customers
- [www.myDomain.com/us](http://www.myDomain.com/us) - for US customers

What would be the correct way of tracking data (including Enhanced Ecommerce) from these three sites?  I'd like to be able to see all the data as one, but also split out to view base/eu/us separately.  My current GA implementation is through GTM.

I'm currently considering either Content Grouping, Custom Dimensions, or Custom Metrics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is have a global view and split out to other 3 views the languages with dedicate filter based pagepath, like /eu.

Comment: Ah of course that seems so obvious now you've suggested it!  Should I still attempt to strip out the localising subfolders from the url path?

Comment: A view with filter to include path start with '/eu', another with filter to include path start with '/us' and with filter to exclude path start with '/us' or '/eu' (with a regex).

Comment: Understood thanks.  What about path based statistics?  Won't the unfiltered view display them un-grouped, e.g. /promotion-1, /eu/promotion-1, /us/promotion-1?